# In PHP, I have a table with repeating dropdowns but while multiple drops down lists are showing only the first is populated

Tags: php, mysql

I have a result-set that display many rows in a table, and in one of the table cells I'm adding a dropdown with options.  The very first row of the table has a drop down that populates correctly with MySQL data, but in the rows below, while the drop down is indeed there, there's are no options in it.  Thanks!

```
<?php while ($expenses = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
?>

 <tr>
 <td><?php echo number_format($expenses["amount"], 2);?></td>
 <td><?php //echo $expenses["vendor"];?></td>
 <td><?php //echo $expenses["description"];?></td>

<!-- code for type dropdown-->

<td><select>
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($type_result_set)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row["type_name"];?>"><?php echo $row["type_name"];?></option>
<?php
}
?>

</td>
</select>


<!-- this section resumes table after drop down-->
 <td><?php echo $expenses["department"];?></td>
 <td><input name="done" type="checkbox" id="done"></td>
 <td><textarea name="notes" id="notes"></textarea></td>
 </tr>


<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Is there code (not shown) that re-initializes `$type_result_set`? Otherwise, once it's been run through for the first row, it won't return any more values.

Comment: fix your markup, you're closing the <td> before the <select>

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your markup, make sure you close the `<select>` tag before the `<td>`

```
<td>
<select>
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($type_result_set)) {?>
<option value="<?php echo $row["type_name"];?>"><?php echo $row["type_name"];?></option>
<?php}?>
</select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put the data from `$type_result_set` in a array (using a while loop) before entering the `$expenses = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` loop. Once `$type_result_set` is looped through once, it won't give any more data, so you should store it beforehand.